# Selecting all text when clicking or pressing TAB on JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

How can I set up the JTextField so that, when the user clicks on it or presses the TAB key, the text of JTextField is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a FocusListener to the JTextField, and in focusGained(), call selectAll().

In code, this looks like this:

```
yourTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
       ((JTextField)e.getSource()).selectAll();
    }

    @Override
       public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the selection start to the begining it is on end by default.
This is he shortest implementation possible.

```
jTextField1.setSelectionStart(0);
```

Comment: @Halil Have you tried this way? Its a lot more simple than SurfMan way